# Binding with variable for username/pwd

Tags: python-3.x, flask, ldap3

I am trying to take login input and pass to our AD server to authenticate a user.  I keep getting an error : invalidCredentials, but I have verified the credentials a number of times.  Am I using the variables correctly?  Any feedback is appreciated. I currently have the following code.

```
`@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    server = Server('dc.ourcompany.com', use_ssl=True, get_info=ALL)
    conn = Connection(server, user='%s' %username, password='%s' %password, raise_exceptions=False)
    conn.open()
    conn.bind()
    if not conn.bind():
        print('error in bind',  conn.result)`
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
error in bind {'dn': '', 'message': '80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A8, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1\x00', 'result': 49, 'referrals': None, 'saslCreds': None, 'type': 'bindResponse', 'description': 'invalidCredentials'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added in NTLM authentication, and that seemed to have resolved the issue.